# Windows7 activation error 8007232b

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I am trying to activate my msdn provided Win 7 enterprise but I get an error about a DNS.  This is a royal pain to deal with.  How am I supposed to activate this installation?

Answer (score 6):

Weird activation bug in Vista and W7. Fixed by changing the product key. [Instructions.](http://www.windows-consulting.net/blog/error-message-code-0x8007232b-when-you-try-to-activate-windows-7-enterprise/) [More details](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/08/07/0x8007232b-dns-name-does-not-exist-error-on-windows-vista-or-server-2003-activation/)

Answer (score 1):

Phone Microsoft Support, they will give you a code to type in manually, another royal pain in the butt, but should work.